# How to select AngularJS model on first time load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using AngularJS to populate a select option list.

And I'm selecting an option by default depending on a field isMandatory.
But the problem is I can't get the id of the selected item on first time load.

It works when I change the option.

Please check this plunker code: http://plnkr.co/edit/U2dVeo1vwZZPFKVhPleV?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in list">
```

and a function to set the initially selected item:

```
angular.forEach($scope.list, function(item, key){
  if(item.isMandatory) {
    $scope.selectedItem = item.id;
  }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9TFdpmLnos5qZzGQwyi2?p=preview)

Comment: I'm using $resource to fetch the item, maybe because of that the control never goes inside forEach. What should i do?

Comment: @LittleLebowski, put the forEach inside the `query()` callback function.  (You could also `$watch` the `list` for a change and put the forEach inside the watch callback.)

Comment: I'm marking this as correct answer as it works, but in my case I'll be using AngularUI-Select2 which states that the directive doesn't work with ng-options and recommends to use ng-repeat. Any workaround of this solution that uses ng-repeat?

Comment: @LittleLebowski, just add the forEach to your controller in your original Plunker to set the intial model value.  See [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wbVDeF96ckd6BWCdcNoU?p=preview).  In this new plunker, I also converted the number to a string, since in ng-repeat the values are strings, not numbers.